# List of database table types and security permissions?

Tags: database, oracle, schema

I can't find any list for the various table types and if possible the basic default 'good practice' security permissions for tables types. I am referring to a complete list like this: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3616476/Types-of-Tables-in-Oracle.htm

The above list has few general but not in depth like Lookup tables differ between user lookups, sytem lookups, temporary lookups etc..

Comment: what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: List of possible table types, so I can 1) Assign prefix to the diffeent table types, 2) create basic security guidelines for the table types.

Answer (score 4):

That article is just talking about the different ways that tables might be used, e.g. "staging" tables versus "operational" tables.

The basic default "good practice" security permissions are the same no matter what type of table you're designing:

**Grant only the minimum necessary privileges.**

What more is there?

As for your table prefixes, this is very much a subjective question. There is no "right answer" except "whatever seems to cause least confusion for your developers and maintainers".

Comment: But please NOT the prefix "tbl_" on every table!